# I need advice to eliminate code duplication in Java with SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, inheritance, architecture, clean-architecture

I have two RestControllers that inject two interfaces that are very similar, they have methods with the same name and different data mapping logic, they also have generic methods that implement the same logic. I have transferred the generic methods to another class so as not to duplicate the implementation.

I have following questions:

1- Can a generic service (GenericFileService) be injected into other more specific services (FileServiceA and FileServiceB) or is it considered bad practice? why?

2- What would be the way to eliminate duplicate code (Object download();) in the two interfaces (A and B) with their implementations that encapsulate the calls to the generic methods of the injected generic interface?

In rest controller interfaces A and B are injected, so to call the generic methods, they have to be included in the interface and have an implementation. Currently it duplicates the encapsulation calls, so the idea is to make interfaces A and B extend the generic interface and the implementations of Interfaces A and B extend the generic implementation. This form seems to me to be quite busy and I do not think it is good practice.

Example of solution with inheritance:

- class FileServiceAImpl extends GenericFileServiceImpl implements FileServiceA
- interface FileServiceA extends GenericFileService

Is there any correct way to solve it and that the code is clean and well readable? Or will it be necessary to completely redesign it?

Advice and constructive criticism are welcome. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Why don't interfaces FileServiceA and FileServiceB extend a common interface which defines the ```download()``` and ```getList()``` methods?

Comment: Same goes for their impl classes

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use *inheritance* instead of *composition*. In this case, you would make your `FileSystemA/BImpl` classes *extend* `GenericFileSystemImpl` instead of having a field of that type.

Whether or not this is a better solution in your case, is up to you. At any rate, you have already eliminated (most of) the code duplication by having a generic service implement the common logic. That is the most important part.

Comment: So for your taste and based on your experience, do you think that this solution is not bad?

The inheritance option I don't like is that I first have to extend the generic interface in interfaces A and B and then re-extend the generic implementation in service classes A and B. It doesn't seem like a very clean solution to me.

Thank you very much for your time and your answer.

Comment: @OleksandrVeretennykov Yes, I think your solution is fine. In general with services like this, I'd prefer composition over inheritance. It's easier to work with and easier to test. The only downside (if you can call it that) is your DI framework has to do a little more work.

Answer (score 1):

You could define a download interface

```
public interface DownloadService {
    Object download();
}
```

Which is then extended by all your interfaces which provide the download method:

```
public interface FileService<E> extends DownloadService {
    List<E> getList();
}
```

and

```
public interface GenericFileService extends DownloadService {}
```

You don't really need the `GenericFileService` but it will be easier without changing too much of your setup. Otherwise you'd mess up your autowiring by having multiple implementations of the interface you're injecting.

Then your FileServices can also just be marker interfaces:

```
public interface FileServiceA extends FileService<ObjectA> {}
```

and

```
public interface FileServiceB extends FileService<ObjectB> {}
```

I tried to change as little of your code as possible and this is the closest I could get.

Comment: I'm going to try it, to see if I can understand the implementation well and if I like the final result.

Thank you so much.